# can I decrypt an encrypted data if I have input and output and the method but dont have the key?

Tags: encryption

This is a security question, What if I give to the user:

- a sample input before encrypting
- a sample output after encrypting
- the encryption method

but I did not provide the correct key for the encryption method, would it be easily that the user can find the encryption key?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, a good algorithm does not allow known-plaintext attacks, but flagged because not a question for stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not easy, no. It does make cracking the encyption easier though. You have confirmed the exact logic for producing the encrypted string, and given the attacker an example to test with.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the algorithm we suppose to be something public, hence you do not provide any kind  of critical information to reveal the key. Moreover, you describe a known-plaintext attack where the user has a pair of plaintext and the corresponding ciphertext which it suppose  to be something public to all users. A strong cipher algorithm should be difficult to break by recovering the encryption-decryption key(symmetric) having in mind only these two factors.